# What is an AppDelegate implementation? PushNotificationIOS

Tags: react-native

The documentation for this isn't clear.

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/pushnotificationios.html

> And then in your AppDelegate implementation add the following:

Is it referring to putting this code below `@implementation AppDelegate` like this:

```
#import "RCTPushNotificationManager.h"
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "RCTRootView.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

// Required to register for notifications
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:(UIUserNotificationSettings *)notificationSettings { [RCTPushNotificationManager didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:notificationSettings]; }  // Required for the register event.
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken { [RCTPushNotificationManager didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:deviceToken]; }  // Required for the notification event.
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)notification { [RCTPushNotificationManager didReceiveRemoteNotification:notification]; }  // Required for the localNotification event.
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification { [RCTPushNotificationManager didReceiveLocalNotification:notification]; } - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)error { NSLog(@"%@", error); }

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions

{
  NSURL *jsCodeLocation;

  ...
}

@end
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it should be inside @implementation in AppDelegate.

Here is my AppDelegate.m in a app using PushNotificationIOS
[My AppDeligate.m](https://gist.github.com/jakkra/3712ceace1530bb478a29840964ef004)

Answer (score 0):

That's how your AppDelegate looks like after adding @react-native-community/push-notification-ios configurations :- [AppDelegate.m](https://gist.github.com/haidar4243/86c7b4a72ff329ce5399956afd2b510f)